# Why compile fails inlining Consumer<ZipEntry> but works externally?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I've created a utility that combines zip file archives into a single archive.  In doing so,  I originally had the following method (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675052/what-is-the-difference-between-these-constructs-such-that-one-wont-compile) for some background on `ExceptionWrapper`):

```
private void addFile(File f, final ZipOutputStream out, final Set<String> entryNames){
    ZipFile source = getZipFileFromFile(f);
    source.stream().forEach(ExceptionWrapper.wrapConsumer(e -> addEntryContent(out, source, e, entryNames)));
}
```

Here is the code for `ExceptionWrapper.wrapConsumer` and `ConsumerWrapper`

```
public static <T> Consumer<T> wrapConsumer(ConsumerWrapper<T> consumer){
    return t -> {
        try {
            consumer.accept(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    };
}
public interface ConsumerWrapper<T>{
    void accept(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

This results in the compilation errors:

```
Error:(128, 62) java: incompatible types: 
java.util.function.Consumer<capture#1 of ? extends java.util.zip.ZipEntry> 
cannot be converted to 
java.util.function.Consumer<? super capture#1 of ? extends java.util.zip.ZipEntry>

Error:(128, 97) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.zip.ZipEntry
```

However, the following change compiles just fine and works as expected:

```
private void addFile(File f, final ZipOutputStream out, final Set<String> entryNames){
    ZipFile source = getZipFileFromFile(f);
    Consumer<ZipEntry> consumer = ExceptionWrapper.wrapConsumer(e -> addEntryContent(out, source, e, entryNames));
    source.stream().forEach(consumer);
}
```

Notice that all I did was pull out the in-lined creation of the `Consumer` into a separate variable.  Any spec experts know what changes for the compiler when the `Consumer` is in-lined?

EDIT:  As requested, this is the signature of `addEntryContent(...)`:

```
private void addEntryContent(final ZipOutputStream out, 
                             final ZipFile source, 
                             final ZipEntry entry, 
                             final Set<String> entryNames) throws IOException {
```

Comment: The type inference rules around generics and lambdas are fairly complicated, but that's the area you should be looking at in the JLS. It is even possible that it's a compiler bug.

Comment: By the way, what is the signature of `addEntryContent()`?

Comment: @biziclop edited to include sig of `addEntryContent`.  Good suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the rather unusual signature of [`ZipFile.stream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#stream--):

```
public Stream<? extends ZipEntry> stream()
```

it was defined this way because it allows the subclass `JarFile` to [override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#stream--) it with the signature:

```
public Stream<JarEntry> stream()
```

Now when you call `stream()` on a `ZipFile` you get a `Stream<? extends ZipEntry>` with a `forEach` method with the effective signature `void forEach(Consumer<? super ? extends ZipEntry> action)` which is a challenge to the type inference.

Normally, for a target type of `Consumer<? super T>`, the functional signature `T → void` gets inferred and the resulting `Consumer<T>` is compatible to a target type of `Consumer<? super T>`. But when wildcards are involved, it fails as a `Consumer<? extends ZipEntry>` is inferred for your lambda expression which is considered not to be compatible with the target type `Consumer<? super ? extends ZipEntry>`.

When you use a temporary variable of type `Consumer<ZipEntry>`, you have explicitly defined the type of the lambda expression and that type is compatible with the target type. Alternatively you can make the type of the lambda expression more explicit by saying:

```
source.stream().forEach(ExceptionWrapper.wrapConsumer(
                        (ZipEntry e) -> addEntryContent(out, source, e, entryNames)));
```

or simply use a `JarFile` instead of `ZipFile`. The `JarFile` doesn’t mind if the underlying file is a plain zip file (i.e. has no manifest). Since `JarFile.stream()` doesn’t use wildcards, the type inference works without problems:

```
JarFile source = getZipFileFromFile(f);// have to adapt the return type of that method
source.stream().forEach(ExceptionWrapper.wrapConsumer(
                        e -> addEntryContent(out, source, e, entryNames)));
```

Of course, it will now infer the type `Consumer<JarEntry>` rather than `Consumer<ZipEntry>` but that difference has no consequences…

Comment: As a side note, `ZipFile.stream()` violates their [own recommendation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html): “*Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards*”. They are so right…

Comment: Awesome explanation.  When I saw `Consumer<? super capture#1 of ? extends java.util.zip.ZipEntry>`, I went, "WTF is that?"  It's what prompted me to ask the question since my brain has a hard enough time with 1 wild card in generic statements, let alone two.

Comment: I wonder whether it would be more appropriate to make a `ZipFile<T extends ZipEntry>` and return `Stream<T>`...

Comment: I don't see why they made the `stream()` return `Stream<? extends ZipEntry>` instead of just `Stream<ZipEntry>`.  I mean, I see how it allows the override in `JarFile`, but since they already created [`getJarEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getJarEntry-java.lang.String-) along side `getEntry()`, why not do the same and create `public Stream<JarEntry> jarEntryStream()` in `JarFile`?

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: because then, `ZipFile` suddenly turns into a generic class causing tons of raw type warnings on legitimate use cases.

Comment: @MadConan: given the now established patterns, having `zipEntries()` and `jarEntries()` would fit better than `stream()` anyway. But don’t ask me, most probably, this pattern hadn’t established yet when they made that method…

Comment: @Holger, this did not stop Swing developers from adding generic arguments to [JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) and several other classes in JDK 7, while in JDK 6 they were [raw](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html).

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: that’s justified as these classes have indeed a collection like functionality which suffered from the absence of a type parameter. It’s rather incomprehensible why this took so long, as that’s missing since Java 5. However, the case of `ZipFile` is different as the only valid type argument would be `<ZipEntry>`, so it’s not really a generic class, it’s just pretending to be generic to support that single subclass…